input() function: is it possible to distinguish when user hit <esc> or <enter> keys?
As per question. If in my script I have input('Add your text here:') and run it, is there a way to distinguish if at some point user hit enter or esc?

If an empty answer is valid, then I'm afraid there is no way to distinguish between abort and empty-answer.

An empty string is valid for the use-case I need.
